# Spock Testing when method under test contains closure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, multi-tenant, spock

I'm using grails plugin multi-tenant-single-db.  Within that context I need to write a spock test in which we temporarily remove the tenant restrictions.  Location is my Tenant, so my method looks like this:

```
def loadOjectDetails(){
       Location.withoutTenantRestriction{
          // code here to retrieve specific items to the object to be loaded
          render( template: "_loadDetails", model:[ ... ]
       }
}
```

The method runs as expected, but trying to put method under test coverage the error output suggests that:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.myPackage.myController.Location.withoutTenantRestriction() is applicable for argument types:
```

and a stacktrace that stems on from there.

Do I need to Stub this? The withoutTenantRestriction is a wrapper around my entire method logic.

UPDATE:
The test code looks like this:

```
 given:
    params.id = 3002
    currentUser = Mock(User)
    criteriaSetup()
    controller.getSalesOrder >> salesOrders[2]

    when:
    controller.loadOrderManageDetails()

    then:
    (1.._) controller.springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() >> currentUser


    expect:
    view == 'orderMange/orderManageDetail'
    model.orderInstance == salesOrders[2]
```

Comment: What does the test code look like?

Comment: I updated the question with my test code as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You should be stubbing it as is created at run time not compile time. 
You could stub it like below:

```
Your_Domain.metaClass.withoutTenantRestriction{Closure closure ->
            closure.call()
}
```

This way your regular code will work in test cases. Also,as in `withoutTenantRestriction` it basically starts a new hibernate session, which doesn't matter much as now you have stubbed the closure, you could perform desired action in place of calling `closure.call()` only.

Also, same could be applied to `withThisTenant`.

In integration tests you don't need to stub it as is loading the whole environment.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Just a question about replacing `closure.call()` with the code that would be performed.  Would the test then fail when or if the original method is altered?

Comment: Well if you put code there that code will be executed but no original method code as it was passed to closure.